# Integration tests repository class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

Is it possible to change the database (entity framework) for integration tests, so that I can create test records in my database and throw everything away when the tests are done?

Now I am polluting the database that I use for local development.

PS: I realized this must be pretty basic stuff, but for some reason I am unable to find documentation on this.

Comment: It would hugely depend on how your application is currently set up. EF context's allow connection strings in the constructor.. but how are your context's created? If you're using a DI/IoC framework this would be extremely easy to switch back and forwards..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was looking for. Simply changing the database name is easier then I hoped for. You can change the database name by simply constructing the DbContext with a name.

```
new ApplicationContext("TestDatabase")
```

The implementation of the ApplicationContext:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext()
    {
    }

    public ApplicationContext(string databaseName) : base(databaseName)
    {
    }
}
```

Running my tests I created a separate database that I can use for testing.

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this is to wrap each test in a [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) block, either explicitly for each test or in the setup method. If the scope is not committed, the changes are rolled back. [Here](http://ryangaraygay.com/unit-testing-data-access-with-net-transactionscope/) is an example.